# How is this an application of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, compactness

I am reading a proof of this theorem:

The continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is coercive if and only if for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $\{x|f(x) \le \alpha\}$ is compact.

The beginning of the proof says:

> Since $f$ is continuous, then the set $\{x|f(x) \le \alpha \}$ is
>   closed. Thus, by Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem, it remains only to show
>   that any set of the form $\{x|f(x) \le \alpha \}$ is bounded….

My understanding of Bolzano Wierstrass was that it states that *a set is compact if and only every sequence in the set contains a subsequence which converges to a point in the set*.

I do not understand how we are applying the Bolzano Weierstrass(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) theorem here.  What are we calling a “subsequence” in this context?

Also, as a reminder, coercive means $$\lim_{||x||\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\infty$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercive_function

How is this an application of the Bolzano Weierstrass theorem?

P.S. As a follow up question, does this proof imply that a continuous function is always has an domain which is closed?  If not, then why are we allowed to say that the "contiuity of $f$ implies the closedness of the sets $\{x|f(x)\le \alpha\}$

Comment: Pretty sure they meant Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: Yeah ^that’s it.

Answer (score 2):

The Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem is essentially saying that

> In Euclidean spaces, sequentially compact $\iff$ closed and bounded.

Heine–Borel, which is probably the appropriate one here, says that

> In Euclidean spaces, compact $\iff$ closed and bounded.

Of course, for metric spaces compact $\iff$ sequentially compact, so the difference is not very important in this case.

C.f. [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Sequential_compactness_in_Euclidean_spaces).

---

Regarding the P.S., you can go directly using the sequential version of closed: suppose that $x_n$ is a sequence of points, all of which have have $f(x_n) \leq \alpha$, and that $x_n \to x$. Then $\alpha - f(x) = (\alpha - f(x_n)) + (f(x_n)-f(x))$, and the first term is nonnegative, the second tends to zero as $n \to \infty$ by continuity, so we also have $f(x) \leq \alpha$, so the set is closed.

A continuous function need not have a closed domain ($1/x$ is continuous on $(0,1]$, which is neither open nor closed), but here the domain is the closed set $\mathbb{R}^n$, so we can do this.

Comment: Thanks @Chappers, but I still do not understand how the application of Heine-Borel allows us to say that we *only* need to show that the set is bounded.

Comment: You want to show the set is compact. By H-B, this is equivalent to showing that it is closed and bounded. Since $f$ is continuous, you know the set is closed. So now it is necessary to show that it is bounded.

Comment: I see.  Sorry - I actually thought that was inherent in hte definition of "compactness", so I didn't understand why B-W was even necessary!